# Should std::move drop constness?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, move-semantics

The following code compiles and runs on MSVC2010, should it?

```
const std::string s = "foo";
std::string s2(std::move(s));
```

I can see why this probably wouldn't break anything since if I take s's internals I have to know that no one is going to use it so it dosn't matter that I'm dropping const. However what about where the compiler implements const objects in ROM (in an embedded application)? Would the move turn into a copy then? Or should MSVC be giving me an error?

Comment: maybe it compiles due to some optimization?

Comment: @icepack no, compilation, especially checks on const correctness etc. come way before optimization.

Comment: @icepack the golden rule of optimisation is the as-if rule. The compiler cannot make optimisations that don't behave as-if they were not applied (in terms of observable behaviour and within the rules st forth by the language).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think `std::move(T const&)` just returns `T const &&`. This means, it will just not actually be moved from (since move assignment operators / constructors don't match the param type).

What happens is, that the constructor taking `T const&` matches the *`lvalue`* (the *variable* typed `T const &&`) and as such, the move degrades into a copy.

Comment: @AndyProwl seems like every time I ask something on here you are there to answer :) your like the nerd form of a guardian angel ;)

Comment: I think the second sentence is a bit misleading. Lvalue reference parameters *never* match rvalue references, but a temporary can bind to a const-lvalue reference...

Comment: @PorkyBrain That's an awesome description of [SO]. Mind if I steel the tweet? :)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. I hope I have clarified that now :)

Comment: @KerrekSB there's no temporary though (references are not objects). But `std::move(...)` is an xvalue, and `const&` can bind to xvalues.

Comment: @sehe: What he ↑ said... :-)

Comment: PorkyBrain/@ArneMertz It was a challenge to condense it into one tweet: https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/304587287046541312

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks - I realized that I'm not understanding this well. So, the value of the `move` expression is something that can bind to const-lvalue references, although it's not a temporary, right? And that's why C++11 needs those new value categories?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh sry, I knew that. Just didn't think it was important enough to mention :) You'll note I didn't change my wording in that respect :)

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, more or less that. xvalues are both glvalues and rvalues, so they can bind to both rvalue refs or lvalue refs (but IIRC rvalue refs are preferred when resolving overloads, so they get picked first).

Comment: @KerrekSB I found Scott Meyer's "Universal References" article very enlightnening: a _variable_ with an _ravlue-ref type_ is itself an _lvalue_ (all variables are).

Comment: @KerrekSB: We don't have a *variable* of rvalue-ref type here though

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `const&` can bind to any rvalue, why mentioning xvalues?

Comment: @sehe: That much I know, but that's not the issue here, since we don't have an id-expression, but a `std::move` call expression... non?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes An rvalue (including an xvalue) will not bind to an lvalue ref unless it's an lvalue ref to const.

Answer (score 23):

This is no difference to

```
const std::string f() { return "foo"; }
std::string s2 = f();
```

This was, at one time, recommended C++03, and the Committee did not *break* this code when introducing rvalue references. It simply degrades into a copy.

Comment: Nice comparison to an implicit move situation. +1

Comment: How is there no different? In OP's post s2 is constructed using (casted) rvalue reference, and in this s2 is from rvalue itself.

Comment: @texasbruce: In the OP, there's no cast. `std::move` is a function just like `f()` in this example. Therefore, in both cases s2 is initialized with the return value of the function itself.